# Alternatives to caseInsensitiveCompare sortDescriptor

Tags: objective-c, sorting

An array to be sorted has strings such as:

```
200burgers
1apple
2burgers
11apples
```

and similar.  When sorting ascendingly with caseInsenstive, I get:

```
11apples
1apple
200burgers
2burgers
```

Which makes sense, but I would prefer a lexicographical sort that put "1" before "10", "10" before "100", &c., such as:

```
1apple
11apples
2burgers
200burgers
```

Must I construct a custom comparator or is there some other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll probably need a custom comparator, but it'd be something really simple:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES comparator:^(id one, id two) {
    return [one compare:two options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: This looks really good.  As a side note, I fooled around and got the sort I wanted switching from caseInsensitiveCompare to localizedStandardCompare.  But that seems to be a happy accident, and I will use your answer in future caes where I am not so lucky...

Comment: Come to think of it, -localizedStandardCompare is often a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't adjust the string then you would have to write a custom comparator to search the string for the non-digit and sort on the string part then number part.

Much easier however would be to have those two elements as separate objects and use `- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors`

Where you will sort on "string" and then "count". Lexically the numbers will not sort correctly in the concatenated form you have posted.